# Does the "CaptureChangeMySQL” processor in Apache Nifi connect to Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, apache, apache-nifi, cdc

I am trying to set up a CDC (change data capture) template in Apache Nifi using the CaptureChangeMySQL processor in Apache NiFi and I get the below error:

*CaptureChangeMySQL: Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
Could not connect binlog client to any of the specified hosts due to: BinaryLogClient was unable to connect in 30000ms*

Processor Configuration: 
[CaptureChangeMySQL Processor Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxF7G.png)

I am not sure, if this processor can be used to connect to Oracle Databases, and whether it reads the oracle redo logs for CDC. Can somebody help ?

It works fine with MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality in the processor is specific to MySQL and cannot be used to connect to Oracle.